# Deserialize JSON strings with different formats to instances of the same Java class

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

What is the best way to deserialize JSON strings with different formats to instances of the same Java class using Jackson?

For example, I have information about users fetched from different sources:

Format 1:

```
"user" : {
  "name"     : "John",
  "age"      : 21,
  "email"    : "john@mail.com",
  "location" : "NYC"
}
```

Format 2:

```
{
  "user" : "John",
  "mail" : "john@mail.com",
  "age"  : "21"
}
```

Format 3:

```
{
  "who"      : "John",
  "contacts" : "john@mail.com",
  "age"      : 21
}
```

And I want to deserialize all these strings into instances of following class:

```
public class User {
  public String name;
  public String email;
  public int age;
}
```

Maybe there is a way to define mapping from JSON fields to Java fields via Map rather then annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dig Jackson documentation and found two solutions.

Here is my Java class:

```
public class User {
    protected String name;
    protected String email;
    protected int age;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + ": [ " + email + ", " + age + " ]";
    }
}
```

First solution is to create custom PropertyNamingStrategy:

```
public class MappingPropertyNamingStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategy {

    Map<String, String> nameMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        nameMap = map;
    }

    @Override
    public String nameForGetterMethod(MapperConfig<?> cfg,
                                      AnnotatedMethod method,
                                      String defaultName) {
        return mapName(defaultName);
    }
    @Override
    public String nameForSetterMethod(MapperConfig<?> cfg,
                                      AnnotatedMethod method,
                                      String defaultName) {
        return mapName(defaultName);
    }
    @Override
    public String nameForField(MapperConfig<?> cfg,
                               AnnotatedField field,
                               String defaultName) {
        return mapName(defaultName);
    }

    protected String mapName(String name) {
        if (nameMap.containsKey(name)) {
            return nameMap.get(name);
        } else {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then define mapping from User fields to appropriate JSON fields:

```
    String json1 = "{ \"user\": { \"name\": \"John\", \"age\": 21, \"email\": \"john@mail.com\", \"location\": \"NYC\" }}";
    String json2 = "{ \"user\": \"John\", \"mail\": \"john@mail.com\", \"age\": \"21\" }";
    String json3 = "{ \"who\": \"John\", \"contacts\": \"john@mail.com\", \"age\": 21 }";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MappingPropertyNamingStrategy namingStrategy = new MappingPropertyNamingStrategy();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    Map<String, User> res = mapper.readValue(json1, new TypeReference<Map<String, User>>() {});
    System.out.println(res.get("user"));


    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(namingStrategy);
    namingStrategy.setMap(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                put("name", "user");
                put("email", "mail");
            }});
    System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json2, new TypeReference<User>(){}));


    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(namingStrategy);
    namingStrategy.setMap(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                put("name", "who");
                put("email", "contacts");
            }});

    System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json3, new TypeReference<User>(){}));
```

Another solution is to use mixins:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"location"})
abstract class FirstFormat {
}

abstract class SecondFormat {
    @JsonProperty("user")
    public abstract void setName(String name);
    @JsonProperty("mail")
    public abstract void setEmail(String email);
    public abstract void setAge(int age);
}

abstract class ThirdFormat {
    @JsonProperty("who")
    public abstract void setName(String name);
    @JsonProperty("contacts")
    public abstract void setEmail(String email);
    public abstract void setAge(int age);
}
```

And then you need only associate it with User class:

```
    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.addMixInAnnotations(User.class, FirstFormat.class);
    Map<String, User> res = mapper.readValue(json1, new TypeReference<Map<String, User>>() {});
    System.out.println(res.get("user"));        

    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.addMixInAnnotations(User.class, SecondFormat.class);
    System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json2, new TypeReference<User>(){}));

    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.addMixInAnnotations(User.class, ThirdFormat.class);
    System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json3, new TypeReference<User>(){}));
```

I think, mixins is the best solution, because it provide more control.

Comment: What you are calling "mixins" are actually called "annotations". Anyways, well digged! I dig it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, whether or not `"user" :` should be a part of the JSON string, you can manipulate that using normal String manipulation in Java.

For the second part, about mapping `mail` to `email` and such, you can use setters

```
public class User {
  public String name;
  public String email;
  public int age;

  public void setMail(String value) {
     this.email = value;
  }
}
```

The `setMail`-method here will be detected by Jackson and will be called for the `mail` property in example 2. You can add such set-methods for all the mappings you would like (contacts, user, who).

Comment: Approach you've suggested looks good, but I'm afraid of billions setters that I'll have to add if more different formats will be presented. :)

Comment: @Filipp How many variations of "mail", "name" and "age" could you possibly come up with?

Comment: At the moment I have about 5 or 6 combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Directly deserializing your source data to the single target format can quickly become a bit cumbersome and error prone. I'd suggest to define separate classes for the different source formats, implementing an interface specifying a `getUser()` method. This method will produce you desired target format.

This way you have all code specific to the different providers in a single class, and it's easy to add new providers when needed.

Comment: You've described my current implementation. I agree that it's quote easy to add new provider, but it requires a bit more work comparing to  specification of fields name mapping.